# TypeScript: add interface to named function (function declaration)?

Tags: typescript

Just starting out with Typescript, and using interfaces for my functions, like so:

```
interface StringFunction {
    (arg1:string):string
}
```

I can attach that interface to a function if I declare it as a variable:

```
let testFunction:StringFunction = function(arg1) {}
```

but I can't work out how I would (or can?) do it with a named function. This doesn't work:

```
function testFunction:StringFunction(arg1) {}
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK interfaces in TypeScript are more like an interface in C# or Java - it defines an object API, therefore StringFunction is not a function name, its an interface you can implement. In other words, if you had interface `StringFunction` with the function taking string a1, you wouldn't call it like: `StringFunction(arg1)`, but you would have to instantiate a class which implements the StringFunction interface and then: `obj.func(arg1)`

Comment: As far as I can tell, TypeScript just doesn't have a syntax that allows you to specify an interface for a named function like this. Is there a reason you can't stick with the `let testFunction:StringFunction = ...` syntax?

Comment: @smarx I'd assume the reason may be to have a function with name? This is useful during debugging as DevTools show the function name in stack traces. React DevTools also relies on the name of the function for its components in the tree.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it but the syntax is a bit different for named functions.

```
interface StringFunction {
  (arg1:string): string
}

<StringFunction>function testFunction(arg1) {}
```

Here we cast `testFunction` to the interface. `arg1` will be a `string`.
Make sure the type is *before* the `function` keyword.

Comment: Thank you. Any way to do this in tsx files though?

Comment: Unfortunately not that I know of since tsx reserves the "<" char for jsx

Answer (score 2):

The need to explicitly state which interface is being used is a constraint of a nominal type system. TypeScript is structurally typed, so you don't need a way to explicitly state that your function implements the interface.

For example, the `testFunction` below is perfectly acceptable where a `StringFunction` is needed - and the compiler checks that it is.

```
interface StringFunction {
    (arg1:string):string
}

function testFunction(arg1) { return ''; }

var x: StringFunction = testFunction;
```

The following example is to illustrate that type checking occurs:

```
interface StringFunction {
    (arg1:string):string
}

function testFunction(arg1) { return 1; }

var x: StringFunction = testFunction; // Error
```

In this case, `testFunction` is not compatible and the compiler issues a warning.

Additional notes:

In strict mode, your original function will indeed need type information (but the answer still applies).

```
function testFunction(arg1: string) { return ''; }
```

This is only needed where there is no context to infer the types, so the following works in strict mode even though it looks like it is missing a type annotation. The `string` type on `arg1` is a contextual type.

```
var x: StringFunction = (arg1) => { return ''; };
```

Comment: This is likely to not work when you have `strict` flag turned on, because you have to explicitly specify the type for the arguments of the function.

Comment: @nilfalse added further explanation for strict mode.

Comment: I am the only one thinking that this does not answer the question why it is not possible to add type/interface to the function declaration, without using function expression?

Comment: @apieceofbart the beauty of structural vs nominal type systems is that you don't have to tag every implementation of an interface. You can opt to check at the point of consumption, not the point of creation. As far as syntax goes, there isn't a mechanism to mark up a `function x` with an interface, but there _is_ a mechanism to mark up a `const x = function` with an interface.

Comment: @user75525 Thank you for your comment. I did not understand the first 2 sentences but I will do my homework. I understand that you cannot mark up `function x` - just wondering if this is not yet implemented or not possible with Typescript at all. 
My case is that I would like to add types to function components in React without assigning them to variable.

Comment: @apieceofbart see the following link https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZEtADwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA86&dq=pro%20typescript%20structural%20vs%20nominal%20type%20system&pg=PA86#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @apieceofbart there isn't a way to do it - but it is worth asking on GitHub to see if it might be a future feature. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript

Comment: @user75525 thanks a lot for the link and suggestion!