# Typescript named function inside functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to type `handleFoo` with `MyType['foo']`.

```ts
type MyType {
  foo: () => void
}

const Comp: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {

  function handleFoo() {}

  return ...
}
```

I don't want to use Anonymous function like `const handleFoo: MyType['foo'] = () => {}`

I also tried `<MyType['foo']>function handleFoo() {}` like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533756/typescript-add-interface-to-named-function-function-declaration) but it's not working in tsx (`Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'string[]'`)

Comment: `const foo: MyType["foo"] = function () {...}`? Otherwise you have to type the parameters and return value separately.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to know if I could type the function directly

Comment: You'd have to use https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype, I think.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you mean like this? `function handleFoo(...args: Parameters<MyType["foo"]>): ReturnType<MyType["foo"]> {}` lol you're right that would technically work, verbose and funky af tho

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your reason for avoiding the anonymous function, you can still type a function by assigning it to a variable, even if it isn't anonymous:

```
const handleFoo: MyType["foo"] = function () {}
```

Edit: as @jonrsharpe pointed out, there are some utility classes you could use here, but the results, uh, leave something to be desired:

```
function handleFoo(...args: Parameters<MyType["foo"]>): ReturnType<MyType["foo"]> {}
```

Comment: Yes I didn't want to assign to a variable but looks like it's the only way

Comment: @HaJa nope, function declarations can not be typed based on an alias, they must be explicitly typed inline, unlike function expressions.